# Error returned from custom json Umarshaller lacks context

Tags: json, go

I am writing a function that parses a JSON object.  I would like to emit structured error messages that indicate which specific fields have errors in them.

Originally I checked if the error type was `*json.UnmarshalTypeError` and then retrieved the json tag name from its `Field` property.  Unfortunately this fails if the struct to which I'm unmarshalling the JSON has custom types that implement their own `UnmarshalJSON` functions.  The errors they return are my custom errors and there is no way to determine which field from the struct they came from.

Playground contrasting the built in vs custom error: https://play.golang.org/p/auH3PE7j5H

At this point I'm considering changing to using reflection, unmarshalling the object into a map of `json.RawMessage` initially and then unmarshalling one field at a time so that I can identify the problematic field(s).  Is there any simpler way?  This will require me to basically duplicate the internal json package logic to analyze the json tags to figure out which field to unmarshal each raw message into.

Comment: Why not return a `*json.UnmarshalTypeError`?

Comment: @JimB That works, thank you!  I would accept this as the answer if I could. 
 Here's an updated example: https://play.golang.org/p/SXCHEkEp0Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json.UnmarshalTypeError`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#UnmarshalTypeError) is exported, as are all of its fields. There's no reason you can't return this error type from your custom marshalers. In fact, I'd venture this is an *intended use* of this type!

```
func (third *Second) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    return &json.UnmarshalTypeError{
        // ...
    }
}
```